# Calling Assembly code from C++

Tags: c++, linux, g++, x86-64, inline-assembly

I'm trying to write my own I/O library, so the first step is just being able to output a character. So far, this only needs to work on Linux. I wrote what I believe to be a solid `_putc:` label in x86 (with Intel syntax), and I put it in "io.h", then called it from my main file, "test.cpp". Here's the contents of test.cpp:

```
#include "io.h"
extern void _putc(char) __asm__("_putc");
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    _putc('c');
    return 0;
}
```

and here's my io.h:

```
asm(
"\n.intel_syntax noprefix"
"\n.globl _putc"
"\n_putc:"
"\n\tpush [ebp]"
"\n\tmov ebp,esp"
"\n\tmov eax,4"
"\n\tmov ebx,0"
"\n\tmov ecx,[ebp+8]"
"\n\tmov edx,1"
"\n\tint 0x80"
"\n\tret"
"\n.att_syntax" ;return to g++'s at&t syntax
);
```

I'm developing this on a an x86_64 Linux operating system using *G++*

I'm using this to compile:

```
 g++ -o test test.cpp -Wall
```

When run it segfaults immediately. I think my problem is calling convention, but there's no way to be absolutely sure. I tried wrapping the assembly in a function (`void _putc(char c)`) and removing the global label, but that didn't help. I also tried pushing the contents of `ebp` instead of the stuff it points to, but then it wouldn't compile.

NOTE: This has to work with only the line `#include io.h` in the main file (I can move the `extern void _putc(char) __asm__("_putc");` after this works), and it has to work with *C++*, not just *C*. Also, please don't lecture me about function definitions in a header file, that's just what I'm doing.

Comment: There is a way to be absolutely sure: use a debugger.

Comment: I did. It segfaults at `push [ebp]`.

Comment: That's a good point, but it's segfaulting at the beginning, without processing the interrupt. So there must be another problem. Also, I have no idea what 'clobbering' is or how to tell the assembler that I'm doing it, can you explain?

Comment: Of course `push [ebp]` takes the value at memory address pointed to by `ebp` and pushes that. However, I think you mean to push the value of `ebp` with `push ebp`. And if you are getting an error on `push ebp` then I question whether you are compiling as 64 or 32-bit code?

Comment: Things like this are also a disaster waiting to happen with GCC inline assembler: `mov ecx,[ebp+8]`. You are assuming the parameter to `putc` is at a specific place on the stack. But if your code gets optimized it is quite possible the value you are interested in was put in a register.

Comment: Besides the [documentation for assembler templates in _GCC_](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html), you might consider this [introductory tutorial](http://wiki.osdev.org/Inline_Assembly) on GCC assembler templates. Google for tutorial about GCC assembler templates for many other resources

Comment: There is a part of me that thinks you are trying to compile this as a 64-bit program too. My question is this. Are you trying to create a 64-bit program or a 32-bit one?

Comment: You push something on the stack at start of putc but don't pop it off after before the `ret`. I'm thinking at a minimum you intended to have a `leave` instruction before `ret`

Comment: I'm compiling with `g++ -o test test.cpp -Wall` on a 64-bit machine. Beyond that, I'm not doing anything special to produce a 32-bit or 64-bit binary. I was led to believe, also, by various online tutorials that the compiler would handle stack frames after `ret` and that the place of the argument on the stack is guaranteed.

Comment: Okay, I had a sneaking suspicion you were compiling as 64-bit. On a 64-bit development environment (LInux) the default is to create a 64-bit executable, using 64-bit calling conventions. Your code though is very 32-bit ish. If you want to create a 32-bit application you can specify that on the _G++_ command line like this `g++ -m32 -o test test.cpp -Wall` . `-m32` creates 32-bit executables. If you truly are trying to create a 64bit program, the calling convention is totally different. The first parameters are generally passed in registers and not the stack.

Comment: of course. I'm having a hell of a time finding a good tutorial for this, can you point me in the right direction? and maybe post an answer that I can accept?

Comment: The question is quite broad, and really the question resolves down to a request for tutorials (which is off topic). I'm not a good person to ask for a good tutorial as I just use the [64-bit System V ABI reference](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf)  for 64-bit apps and the [_GCC_ assembler template documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) . You can also check out the [x86 wiki tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) with a host of links there

Comment: Using GCC assembler templates is usually a tougher way to learn assembly. As a beginner it may be easier to put your assembler functions in separate assembler ( `.S` ) files and link them with _G++_. Then you don't need to concern yourself with the intricacies involved with inline assembler. In this case it might be less of an issue since you are attempting to inline complete functions.

Comment: I became somewhat competent in assembly a while ago, my big issue is not knowing what the C compiler is trying to do.  Also, this is my first 64-bit machine, which is why I hadn't thought of that :P. Normally I'd pass the arguments to my own functions in registers to save the headache of stack manipulation, so I'm pretty shitty at that. tl;dr I really just need a tutorial on how to do inline assemby, not assembly.

Comment: You should also consider using an 'extern "C" ...' function declaration if you are using the C++ compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With 64-bit code you really need to consider using `syscall` instead of `int 0x80`. The system call uses a 64-bit convention and the system call numbers differ from `int 0x80` in 32-bit code. You can get an idea of the 64-bit system calls in this [table](http://blog.rchapman.org/post/36801038863/linux-system-call-table-for-x86-64). The `sys_write`and `sys_read` calls look like:

> ```
> %rax  System call %rdi              %rsi             %rdx         %r10      %r8   %r9
> 0     sys_read    unsigned int fd   char *buf        size_t count         
> 1     sys_write   unsigned int fd   const char *buf  size_t count
> ```

You need to get acquainted with the [System V 64-Linux ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) if you want to understand how parameters are passed in 64-bit Linux code. Among other things after a call is entered, you generally have to align the stack to a 16-byte boundary if you intend to call other functions or syscalls.

Your code also suffers from a flaw where you pass a character to `sys_write`. `sys_write` requires an address to a buffer that contains the character, not the character itself.

This is a code dump that would work:

```
asm(
"\n.intel_syntax noprefix"
"\n.globl _putc"
"\n_putc:"
"\n\tadd rsp, -8"   // Allocate space on the stack to store the character passed
                    // Also aligns stack back to 16-bye boundary 
                    // with return address already on stack
"\n\tmov [rsp],rdi" // Move the character passed in RDI to memory(stack) for sys_write
"\n\tmov eax,1"     // With 64-bit syscalls RAX = 1 for sys_write
"\n\txor edi,edi"   // 1st parameter to syscall is in RDX. FD = 0
"\n\tlea rsi,[rsp]" // We need to pass pointer to memory containing our char
"\n\tmov edx,1"     // RDX = 1 character to print. Could reuse EAX instead of 1 for src
"\n\tsyscall"       // Make syscall (using syscall instead of int 0x80 for 64-bit)

"\n\tadd rsp, 8"    // Restore stack to state right after function entry
"\n\tret"
"\n.att_syntax prefix" //return to g++'s at&t syntax
);
```

Comment: @RobertHarvey : Thanks for the updates (including grammar). This was a quick answer, and I was in a hurry to type it up. I don't consider this a quality answer though, and I felt it may have been downvote worthy by my usual standards. To me this was a code dump with some sugar. Admittedly, the question is a bit broad though if you want to touch on all the problem areas.